# Were there industrial tycoons with only daughters? How did they handle inheritance?

Tags: industrial-history, gender, inheritance

Industrial mogul John D. Rockefeller had three daughters who lived into adulthood, but just one son, born last. His birth was remarked as fortunate, since it meant that JDR would have an heir.

Since the culture of the eighteenth, nineteenth, and early twentieth centuries was to endow the male heirs with the vast majority of business interests as inheritance, and not to give the daughters any business roles, I am curious about the following:

1. Were there any other highly successful tycoon-types (think Carnegie, Nobel, Astor, Gould, etc.) who had only female offspring?
2. If there were any such tycoons, how did they handle matters of inheritance? Did they train their daughters to business roles?

(There's also an unrelated question, slightly beyond the scope of this question: did any industrial tycoons -- regardless of the gender distribution of their offspring -- train their daughters for business roles?)

Comment: From the "continuity" POV, a daughter is preferable to a son because the tycoon can _pick_ **and** _train_ his son-in-law, but he can only _train_ his son. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Andrew Carnegie had one daughter ([Margaret Carnegie Miller](http://www.nytimes.com/1990/04/21/obituaries/margaret-carnegie-miller-philanthropist-93.html)) and no sons.  She inherited his money and was trustee for his charitable foundation, but Andrew Carnegie gave the bulk of his fortune to charity ([about $350 million out of $480 million](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/amex/carnegie/filmmore/description.html), which was a lot in 1900!).